# Magento 2 Virtual Type real time usage example

Tags: magento2, virtualtype

I am working in Magento2, in that, I hear about some new concept virtual type, so I like to use the virtual type in my development(if it's needed).

But I have gone through so many blogs to understand, but no one has given the clear scope & real-time example.

Here I am looking for your great support to understand the virtual type with real-time usage.

share me your thoughts & idea about the virtual type

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possible ways to use it. The most simple I think is `pool`'s usage for example. The main idea of virtual types is to use an abstract class or interface while you write your code and then overload it with the required implementation.
Imagine that you write a logger. You used network transport to send somewhere your logs and you write a lot of code using TransportInterface methods. To use TCP or UDP transport for logging now you just need to write an implementation for TransportInterface and create virtualType and then put it as a dependency for the logger.
For example:

```
interface TransportInterface {
    public function send($data);
    public function connect();
    public function close();
    ....
}

class Logger
{
    /** transport TransportInterface */
    protected $transport;   
    ...

    public function __construct(
        TransportInterface $transport
        ...
    ) {
        $this->transport = $transport;
    }

    // some code that uses this transport's methods
}

class TransportUdp implement TransportInterface {...}
class TransportTcp implement TransportInterface {...}
```

And I want to send logs from one object (ObjectOne) by UDP (not so necessary) and from payment object(PaymentObject) by TCP (I need to know that all be written). So in both objects, I will put Logger class as a dependency but will write something like:

```
<virtualType name="LoggerUdp">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="transport" xsi:type="object">
              TransportUdp
        </argument>
     </arguments>
</virtualType>

<virtualType name="LoggerTcp">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="transport" xsi:type="object">
             TransportTcp
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>


<type name="ObjectOne">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">LoggerUdp</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="PaymentObject">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">LoggerTcp</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Take a look at `/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/di.xml` at 135 and 145 lines for using if for search module in magento core.

Answer (score 0):

I have created video for easy understanding of virtual type or class. please watch and if you like this video so please like and subscribe my channel. all subscriber will get amazon gift vaucher.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3LbBtSwXUQ&t=13s